# Python packages locations in Ubuntu

Tags: package-management, python, python3, packaging

I try to install python packages in Ubuntu and those packagers successfully. I am not good for Ubuntu that is why I am asking.

But when I check locations of some of python packages, locations are different. There are 3 locations.

I installed pip and pip3 both are for python 3. When I install the python packages I used,

- sudu pip
- sudo pip3
- sudo apt-get

When I check list of packages using pip list or pip3 list some of packages not showing.

Locations

1. /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ - Numpy package
2. /usr/USERNAME/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ - Tensorflow package

   3. /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ - Pandas package
   4. /usr/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ - OpenCV package

Why is that? Can’t I get all one location? How to get all packages list? When I run pip3 list opencv package not showing.